# Who is in charge of keep pg_timezone_names view updated?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, windows-server-2008, postgresql-9.3

In 2007 our president change it from `UTC−04:00` to `UTC−04:30` because children went to school to early. Now on 2016 decide the night arrive very early and revert to `UTC−04:00` in an effort to save electricity.

So how you keep the table `pg_timezone_names`  updated? is there a script I can use, a service I can link to my server?

Or just have to update the table myself everytime I heard something change?

[image]

**EDIT:** I just realize `pg_timezone_names` is a view and not a table. So now the aditional question is how I update the view?

**Second Edit**: Im using windows server 2008 and postgres 9.3

Comment: easier solution would be to eliminate/vote-out any politicians who think messing with timezones is a good idea.

Comment: @MarcB Belive me we are trying to do that.

Comment: you wouldn't update the view. You'd update the underlying table that the view's querying. If that's something in PG, that's easy to do. If it's somehow pulling in data from an external file, then you'd have to update that file.

Comment: @Abelisto - Postgres does not use Windows time zone data.  It compiles IANA tz data into its sources and distributes them with Postgres.  You can use OS tzdata on linux by parameter, but not on Windows. See my answer.

Comment: @MarcB - I think you were joking, but just in case, note that you'd have to vote out literally thousands of people, from high-level presidents, cabinets, congressmen, and parliamentary officials, down to low-level municipality managers.  And of course - they'd be replaced.  It's quite a complex political issue.  I touch on some of this in [this blog post](http://codeofmatt.com/2016/04/23/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change you mention for Venezuela was handled in version 2016d of the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  You can read the 2016d release notes [here](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2016-April/000038.html).

Postgres compiles these updates into each release version of postgres.  You can see the Postgres time zone version history [here](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=history;f=src/timezone/data;hb=HEAD).  From this information, you can see that on 2016-05-06, the 2016d data was added to the Postgres source code.  That means any version of Postgres released after this should have the associated time zone change.

On [the Postgres home page](https://www.postgresql.org/), in the upper-right corner, you can see the latest release versions.  If you wish to stay on 9.3, then update to the latest build which is 9.3.13, released 2016-05-12. Indeed, in [the release notes for 9.3.13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-13.html), it mentions this:

> - Update time zone data files to tzdata release 2016d for DST law changes in Russia and Venezuela. ...

Note that Postgres gives an option `--with-system-tzdata=DIRECTORY` that you can use to stay current using the OS tzdata updates, however it expects to find zic-compiled tzdata such as distributed with Linux, OSX, etc.  This data is not available in this format on Windows.  Therefore, you have to use the tzdata that is shipped with Postgres.

> So how you keep the table pg_timezone_names updated? is there a script I can use, a service I can link to my server?

No, there's no automated way of doing this on Windows (that I'm aware of).  You have to stay updated with the current versions of Postgres.  On Linux, you could automate tzdata updates and use the option flag I mentioned earlier.

> Or just have to update the table myself ...

Do not attempt to manually manipulate the time zone data.  It is much more complex then you may think.

> ... everytime I heard something change?

If you want awareness of time zone data updates, then subscribe to the tz announcements mailing list [at IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

You might also consider subscribing to [Postgres's RSS feed](https://www.postgresql.org/versions.rss).  Do also keep in mind [Postgres's support lifecycle](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), as eventually minor updates will reach end of life, and you'll have to do a more substantial upgrade to stay current.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was hopping I just need update a text file. But looks like I should be planning the upgrade.

Comment: Maybe this should be its own question but I'm confused and don't know where or who to ask.  When I look at pg_timezone_names I see ONE record for "America/Los_Angeles" which contains the abbreviation "PDT".  But we know that "America/Los_Angeles" changes to "PST" in the fall.  Does Postgres automatically handle this change or is there something that needs to run twice a year?  I suppose this explains it but it's still not entirely clear:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html

Comment: @iJames - yes, it should be its own question, but also just read the text on the page you linked to - it explains exactly what you're asking about.